# android studio won't compile retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, retrofit, retrofit2

I generated signed apk of an app I'm working on few dys ago (bea version).
I'm now trying to compile retrofit to the project, sync stage working good but when I try to run the app I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 
'command'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I tried to compile Retrofit on new project and it did compile.

Here are the dependencies (I tried to comment the simple xml alone, didnt help either):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/UniversalImageLoader195.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta3'
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean to compile against Java 8?  Have you tried against Java 7?

Comment: how do i compile aagainst java 7? @WolfBane

Comment: also i did the same thing in the new project and it did compile

Comment: I'm not in front of AS, so from memory: Project Settings -> Project -> Project Language Level -> Set to 7.  If it's worked when it's a new project then i suspect it's some screwy project config.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use some newer version of retrofit:

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching, updating Android Studio and a lot of tries:
multidexEnabled true -> didn't help except only for some part.
What I really needed was:

1. Delete this:

   ```
   compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'"
   ```

(Either it's using some package that is already being compiled by another library or maybe it's making the app to exceed the 64k limit, either way it's dispensable since Retrofit gives you OkHttp built-in).

2.Change simple xml to the following:

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

I'm not sure about the "stax" lines but the "xpp3" definitely popped up in the errors. I found this answer In another post.

I hope it will help others as well.